# Android: Open activity in front of any running app

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to open an activity from the FirebaseMessaging service when some message is received in onMessageReceived method. I want to show that activity in front of any running app like Facebook or Maps. But when the message was received and I started the activity it goes behind the running app.

This is the code I am using to start the activity.

```
val intent = Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java)
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                    startActivity(intent)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starting Android 10 we have some restrictions for starting `Activity` entirelly from the background. check out [DOC](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) for more info and list of [exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions)

Comment: So this is the scenario going on with me.

When such an app attempts to start a new activity, the system places that activity on top of the app's existing task but doesn't navigate away from the currently-visible task. When the user later returns to the app's task, the system starts the new activity instead of the activity that had previously been on top of the app's task.

Comment: Is it possible I can close the app that is running in front when I receive the notification and show my activity?

Comment: no, you can't, its agains policy and user desires. we can't "hijack" users screen and manipulate other apps, enforcing our app to be presented at any moment over any other, user must explicity open it (e.g. by touch interaction, `Notification` press). such behavior isn't just safe (and user friendly), thus new restictions were made